# Custom image toggle button in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this ReactJS code to show a custom image button that toggles between 2 different images for ON and OFF state. Is there a simpler way to do this? I was hoping CSS might be less lines of code, but wasn't able to find a simple example.

The code below passes state up from `<MyIconButton>` to `<MyPartyCatButton>` then to `<MyHomeView>`. My app will have 4 of these custom buttons on the home screen, which is why I factored out `<MyIconButton>`.

btw - this is for a mobile App and I read (and noticed this myself) it's really slow using checkboxes on mobile browsers; that's why I chose to try this without using checkboxes.

**ReactJS code**

```
var MyIconButton = React.createClass({

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("INSIDE: MyIconButton handleSubmit");

    // Change button's state ON/OFF, 
    // then sends state up the food chain via            
    //  this.props.updateFilter( b_buttonOn ).
    var b_buttonOn = false;
    if (this.props.pressed === true) {
      b_buttonOn = false;
    }
    else {
      b_buttonOn = true;
    }
    // updateFilter is a 'pointer' to a method in the calling React component.
    this.props.updateFilter( b_buttonOn ); 
  },

  render: function() {

    // Show On or Off image.
    // ** I could use ? : inside the JSX/HTML but prefer long form to make it explicitly obvious. 
    var buttonImg = "";
    if (this.props.pressed === true) {
      buttonImg = this.props.onpic;
    }
    else {
      buttonImg = this.props.offpic;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="image" src={buttonImg}></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


// <MyPartyCatButton> Doesn't have it's own state, 
// passes state of <MyIconButton> 
// straight through to <MyHomeView>.
var MyPartyCatButton = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <MyIconButton pressed={this.props.pressed} updateFilter={this.props.updateFilter} onpic="static/images/icon1.jpeg" offpic="static/images/off-icon.jpg"/>
    );
  }
});

//
// Main App view
var MyHomeView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    // This is where I'll eventually get data from the server.
    return {
      b_MyPartyCat: true
    };
  },

  updatePartyCategory: function(value) {
    // Eventually will write value to the server.
    this.setState( {b_MyPartyCat: value} );
    console.log("INSIDE: MyHomeView() updatePartyCategory() " + this.state.b_MyPartyCat );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
         <MyPartyCatButton pressed={this.state.b_MyPartyCat} updateFilter={this.updatePartyCategory}/>
        </div>

        // Eventually will have 3 other categories i.e. Books, Skateboards, Trees !
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the right place for "Any thoughts?" kinds of questions.  The react google group, or #reactjs on irc.freenode.net are better places for this kind of question.

Comment: I reworded, how's it look now?

Comment: Great, much better.  I think it just needs one more reopen vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you update the coponent 'pressed' prop dynamically (like you did), simply

```
var MyIconButton= React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var pic= this.props.pressed? this.props.onpic : this.props.offpic
        return <img 
            src={pic} 
            onClick={this.props.tuggleSelection}  //updateFilter is wierd name
        />
    }
})
```

(EDIT: this way, on MyPartyCatButton component, you can pass function to handle 'tuggleSelection' event. event function argument is an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), but you have the button state allready in the wrapper state (the old one, so you should invert it). your code will be something like that:

```
render: function(){
    return <MyIconButton pressed={this.state.PartyCatPressed} tuggleSelection={this.updatePartyCategory} />
}
updatePartyCategory: function(e){
    this.setState( 
        {PartyCatPressed: !this.state.PartyCatPressed} //this invert PartyCatPressed value
    );
    console.log("INSIDE: MyHomeView() updatePartyCategory() " + this.state.b_MyPartyCat )
}
```

)

but if you don't, use prop for defult value:

```
var MyIconButton= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {pressed: this.props.defultPressed}
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        this.setState({pressed: !this.state.pressed})
    },

    render: function(){
        var pic= this.state.pressed? this.props.onpic : this.props.offpic
        return <img 
            src={pic} 
            onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't see how this way will pass the button's toggle state back to the parent <MyPartyCatButton> ? I updated question so correctly show component names in description. Good one on not needing the <form> tag -)